# Delete element in a deeply nested array in jsonb column - Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgres-9.6

I have a table `my_table` with a jsonb column that contains some data, for instance, in a single row, the column can contain the following data:

```
[
  {
    "x_id": "1",
    "type": "t1",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "1", price: 400 },
       { "part_id": "2", price: 500 },
       { "part_id": "3", price: 0 }
     ]
  },
  {
    "x_id": "2",
    "type": "t1",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "1", price: 1000 },
       { "part_id": "3", price: 60 }
     ]
  },
  {
    "x_id": "3",
    "type": "t2",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "1", price: 100 },
       { "part_id": "3", price: 780 },
       { "part_id": "2", price: 990 }
     ]
  }
]
```

I need help finding how to delete an element from the `parts` array given a `x_id` and a `part_id`.

**Example**

given `x_id=2` and `part_id=1`, I need the data to be updated to become:

```
[
  {
    "x_id": "1",
    "type": "t1",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "1", price: 400 },
       { "part_id": "2", price: 500 },
       { "part_id": "3", price: 0 }
     ]
  },
  {
    "x_id": "2",
    "type": "t1",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "3", price: 60 }
     ]
  },
  {
    "x_id": "3",
    "type": "t2",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "1", price: 100 },
       { "part_id": "3", price: 780 },
       { "part_id": "2", price: 990 }
     ]
  }
]
```

PS1: these data cannot be normalized, so that's not a possible solution.

PS2: I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6

PS3: I  have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601616/how-to-delete-array-element-in-jsonb-column-based-on-nested-key-value) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005584/postgres-remove-element-from-jsonb-array?rq=1) but my data structure seems too complex compared to the other questions thus I can't apply the given answers.

**Edit1**: the json data can be big, especially the `parts` array, which can have from as few as 0 element to thousands.

Comment: This is better done outside of SQL.

Comment: I keep that as my last resort in case there is no way to do it with just one query within the database.

Comment: Can you change the JSON structure? Arrays are inherently hard to work with. If you can change it to something like [this](http://dpaste.com/2RHH9BY)  it would be much easier as you can access everything with path like references.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible

Comment: is `x_id` unique for each json element?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `#-` operator (see [`functions-json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html)), you just need to find the path to remove the array element from:

```
select
    data #- p.path
from test as t
    cross join lateral (
        select array[(a.i-1)::text,'parts',(b.i-1)::text]
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.data) with ordinality as a(data,i),
            jsonb_array_elements(a.data->'parts') with ordinality as b(data,i)
        where
            a.data ->> 'x_id' = '2' and
            b.data ->> 'part_id' = '1'
    ) as p(path)
```

or

```
update test as t set
    data = data #- (
        select
            array[(a.i-1)::text,'parts',(b.i-1)::text]
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.data) with ordinality as a(data,i),
            jsonb_array_elements(a.data->'parts') with ordinality as b(data,i)
        where
            a.data ->> 'x_id' = '2' and
            b.data ->> 'part_id' = '1'
    )
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=89b450d3b39bc7bc287de65c4fca3d94)

**update** Ok, there's reasonable comment that update part works incorrectly if given path doesn't exist in the data. I guess in this case you're going to either duplicate expression in the where clause:

```
update test as t set
    data = data #- (
        select
            array[(a.i-1)::text,'parts',(b.i-1)::text]
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.data) with ordinality as a(data,i),
            jsonb_array_elements(a.data->'parts') with ordinality as b(data,i)
        where
            a.data ->> 'x_id' = '2' and
            b.data ->> 'part_id' = '23222'
    )
where
    exists (
        select *
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.data) as a(data),
            jsonb_array_elements(a.data->'parts') as b(data)
        where
            a.data ->> 'x_id' = '2' and
            b.data ->> 'part_id' = '23222'
    )
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cc35c9f6562b5de0af4511c939c5370d)

or you can use self-join:

```
update test as t2 set
    data = t.data #- p.path
from test as t
    cross join lateral (
        select array[(a.i-1)::text,'parts',(b.i-1)::text]
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.data) with ordinality as a(data,i),
            jsonb_array_elements(a.data->'parts') with ordinality as b(data,i)
        where
            a.data ->> 'x_id' = '2' and
            b.data ->> 'part_id' = '23232'
    ) as p(path)
where
    t.ctid = t2.ctid
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=08a5c3797dd310de08d283c0301dc2b9)

Comment: Your solution seems to update the data with empty if the given `x_id` or `part_id` is/are nonexistent.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, this doesn't perform well on very large data, where parts array is more than 1000 elements. I run this on such data and it hangs forever.

Comment: The first snippet, as I was providing an existent path and wanted to see the select outcome before updating.

Comment: I made a quick test (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f0fa28020d2b7bbc1818e8fe0069d509) but honestly I'd not expect this to perform very well on very large amounts of data

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just need another unique column (primary key usually)

create test table

```
create table test_tab(
id serial primary key,
j jsonb
);

insert into test_tab
(j)
values
('[
  {
    "x_id": "1",
    "type": "t1",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "1", "price": 400 },
       { "part_id": "2", "price": 500 },
       { "part_id": "3", "price": 0 }
     ]
  },
  {
    "x_id": "2",
    "type": "t1",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "1", "price": 1000 },
       { "part_id": "3", "price": 60 }
     ]
  },
  {
    "x_id": "3",
    "type": "t2",
    "parts": [
       { "part_id": "1", "price": 100 },
       { "part_id": "3", "price": 780 },
       { "part_id": "2", "price": 990 }
     ]
  }
]');
```

Then split json, filter unnecessary data, and recreate json again:

```
 select id, jsonb_agg( jsonb_build_object('x_id',xid, 'type',type, 'parts', case when inner_arr = '[null]'::jsonb  then parts_arr::jsonb else inner_arr  end) ) 
 from (
    select 
    id, 
     value->>'x_id' as xid, 
    jsonb_agg(inner_arr) as inner_arr,
    max(value->>'parts') as parts_arr,
    max(value->>'type') as type
    from (
        select * , 
        case when value->>'x_id'='2' then jsonb_array_elements(value->'parts')  else NULL end inner_arr 
        from test_tab
        join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j)
        on true
    ) t
    where
    inner_arr->>'part_id'  is distinct from '1'
    group by id, value->>'x_id' 
) t
group by id
```

Comment: I do have a primary key so that's not gonna be a problem, I tried this and it seems to work, I gave some nonexistent ID values and it doesn't crash, so thank you so much. Do you think this solution has any edge cases that might make it crash?

Comment: @ElSam - if your json   always   have same structure  as you shown in question, I  think it  should never crash

Comment: This doesn't perform well on very large data, where `parts` array is more than 1000 elements. I run this on such data and it hangs forever.